# How to select a month and year in calendar with selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I am trying to automate the datepicker, code is running with exit code 0, but month is  not getting clicked.

here is the code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
datefield = driver.find_element_by_id("dateOfBirthInput")
datefield.click()
months = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select[class*='month-select']")
for month in months:
   if month.get_attribute("value") == "June":
        time.sleep(1000)
        month.click()
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the value instead of clicking on the object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Select to get the select tag.

Import Select:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Get the select example:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='react-datepicker__month-select']"))
selected_option = select.first_selected_option
```

**UPDATE**

Tested and working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
datefield = driver.find_element_by_id("dateOfBirthInput")
datefield.click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='react-datepicker__month-select']"))
selected_option = select.first_selected_option.text
print(selected_option)
```

With this code you get the selected month.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I really appreciate it. I tried some other way and now it is working.

Comment: I'm glad it served you. If you do the favor, mark the answer as correct and if you want you could vote for the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and now it is working -

```
datefield = driver.find_element_by_id("dateOfBirthInput")
datefield.click()
months = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select[class*='month-select'] option")
for month in months:
    if month.text == "June":
        month.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        break

days = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class*='datepicker__day']")
for day in days:
    if day.text == "15":
        day.click()
        break
```